# performance issue on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have got a form in html that validates the user input. The problem is it takes a lot of time even on localhost to jump to the 'action' page. Heres the code

```
<form action="Activity.php" method="GET" >

<div style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="chapter" name="chapter"/>
<input type="text" id="book" name="book"/>
<input type="text" id="activity" name="activity"/>
</div>

<input type="image" src="includes/file.png" onClick="return validateForm()" title="Create New Activity" >

</form>
```

The code for validateForm is :

```
function validateForm()
    {
        document.body.style.cursor='wait';
        if(document.getElementById("book").value==null || document.getElementById("book").value==""
                    || document.getElementById("chapter").value==null || document.getElementById("chapter").value=="")
        {
            document.body.style.cursor='default';
            alert("You cannot create an activity at the selected location.");
            return false;
        }



        var name=prompt("Please enter the New Activity Name","New Activity Name");
        if (name==null || name=="")
        {
            document.body.style.cursor='default';
            return false;
        }

        document.getElementById('activity').value=encodeURI(name);
        return true;

    }
```

If I remove the prompt in above function, it instantly jumps to the activity.php page, but if I keep the prompt and ask the activity name, it takes a long time to load the desired page (may be cauze the form submitting process was interrupted by the prompt and on clicking the prompts 'ok' button the submission starts again!!no idea :S)what should be a solution (a fast one) to take input from a user when a form is being submitted? thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using `prompt` to collect information to put in the form?  Aren't you defeating the purpose of the form?

Comment: There is so many things that are not right with your approach. Why don't you use a <input type = "submit"> tag that validates on form submit?

Comment: @pacman : i did try this to see if it makes any difference, but it dint. i am using input type image cauze i need an image as a button that user can click.

Comment: @gddc. good point but i need to take the input when user clicks the image button. in that case this was the only solution that i knew.

Comment: @Salmanmahmood : not that it matters but why do you have your inputs inside a hidden div? If you want to send hidden inputs to the server you just need to specify input type=hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This object does not exist: `document.getElementById('activity')`

Comment: sorry it does exist!! typing error. edited it. thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function validateForm()
    {
        document.body.style.cursor='wait';
        if(document.getElementById("book").value || document.getElementById("chapter").value)
        {
            document.body.style.cursor='default';
            alert("You cannot create an activity at the selected location.");
            return false;
        }



        var name=prompt("Please enter the New Activity Name","New Activity Name");
        if (name)
        {
            document.body.style.cursor='default';
            return false;
        }

        //document.getElementById('activity').value=encodeURI(name);
        return true;

    }
```